# I want to get the value of the custom switch from Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want the current status of the switch so .I tried this but i was facing an error type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'bool'. Thanks in advance

```
statusonoff( Device device) async {
    DocumentSnapshot variable = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('device-configs')
        .document(device.id)
        .get();
    return variable.data['value']['on'];



CustomSwitch(
                    activeColor: Colors.green,
                    value: statusonoff(context, device),
                    onChanged: (value) async {
                      DocumentSnapshot variable = await Firestore.instance
                          .collection('device-configs')
                          .document(device.id)
                          .get();
                      print(variable.data['value']['on']);
                      setState(() {
                        if (variable.data['value']['on'] == false) {
                          value = true;
                          _configMode = "on";
                          _updateDeviceConfig(context, device);
                        } else if (variable.data['value']['on'] == true) {
                          value = false;
                          _configMode = "off";
                          _updateDeviceConfig( device);
                        }
                        status = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

because the method `statusonoff` returns a future, marked as `async` it will now return a type of `Future<T>` and the `value` property of `CustomSwitch` expects a boolean. thats why you are getting this error.

to fix this, simply prepend `statusonoff(context, device)` with `await` .

```dart
CustomSwitch(
                    activeColor: Colors.green,
                    value: await statusonoff(context, device),
//.....
```

Comment: Unexpected text 'await'.
Try removing the text. i am getting this error